# Post data should be bytes. It cannot be type str

Tags: python, python-3.x, push-notification, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send push messages to my phone with my Raspberry pi 3.  (Pushetta). Have found a tutorial which used >import urllib2<. I tried to adapt to Python 3.5.

Error:
POST should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It can not be of type str.

```
import urllib.request
import json


def sendNotification(token, channel, message):
    data = {
        "body" : message,
        "message_type" : "text/plain"
    }

    req = urllib.request.Request('http://api.pushetta.com/api/pushes/{0}/'.format(channel))
    req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    req.add_header('Authorization', 'Token {0}'.format(token))

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))


sendNotification("aab1bxxxx9c2157be2b168d2d5795f869", "Detector", "Hello!")

print("Message sent!")
```

Doing the project for school and do not have much experience. Any help?:)

Comment: There is `str.encode` for this.

Comment: data.encode('utf-8') or how should this look like?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your json string to binary

```
json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Got "Failed building wheel for mrjson" when I try to install

Comment: I'll edit out the mrjson suggestion.  You can write an issue on github if you feel following up to help get that fixed.